# Boolean Value as ECDSA Y-Coordinate

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, ecdsa, elliptic-curve

IANA "[COSE Key Type Parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/cose/cose.xhtml#key-type-parameters)" includes the following:

| Key Type | Name | Label | CBOR Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 (EC2) | crv | -1 | int/tstr |
| 2 (EC2) | x | -2 | bstr |
| 2 (EC2) | y | -3 | bstr/bool |
| 2 (EC2) | d | -4 | bstr |

The information implies that there are cases where the type of y-coordinate for ECDSA can be a boolean value (not an integer value). Does anyone know the reason? I'd like to know how to treat the boolean value when I actually encounter the case.

The relevant specification is [RFC 9053: CBOR Object Signing and Encryption (COSE): Initial Algorithms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9053), [Section 2.1. ECDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9053#name-ecdsa).

Comment: I don't know their reasoning, but remember that for any given x on the curve there are exactly two y values. A boolean also takes on two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found the answer in "2.3.3 Elliptic-Curve-Point-to-Octet-String Conversion" of "[SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf)". The document says that a certain case "*allows the y-coordinate to be represented compactly using a single bit*".